# Django ManyToManyField order is not being kept

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models: Customer and Resources. Customer has a ManyToManyField to Resources. I add the relations from the admin panel e.g.:

```
Customer_1 -> Resource_8, Resource_5, Resource_14
```

The main problem is that I want to insert these relationships in that exact order: resource 8, 5 and 14. But when the admin form is submitted, it saves the relations as follows:

```
Customer_1 -> Resource_5, Resource_8, Resource_14
```

I assume that it is ordering the resources by its ID and not respecting the order they were submitted.

My question is, how do I change this behaviour, so that it always respect the order which was submitted on the admin site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't support ordering in M2M fields, you will need to alter the way your model is defined, specifically you will need to create a [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table and use a custom ordering field for it.